# Discord.py | Trying to dm user and getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, bots, nonetype

I'm trying to dm user when bot just started, and it gets error. When I print user variable it shows me None, but why it is None if id is right? Code is taken from discord.py documentation, so I feel kinda stupid :'d

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    user = bot.get_user(427406422733619200)
    await user.send('Oh no.. I\'m alive..')
```

Comment: You probably can't find the user because the bot isn't in the same server as the user. Can you check if the bot and the user you're DMing are in the same server?

Comment: @Axiumin_ yeah, they are

Comment: Try using `user = await client.fetch_user(427406422733619200)` instead of `user = bot.get_user(427406422733619200)`?

Comment: @Axiumin_ oh, it works! Thank you :з But why .get_user didn't work?

Comment: Cool! I'll post it as an answer then and include the explanation there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `user = bot.get_user(427406422733619200)` with `user = await bot.fetch_user(427406422733619200)`

This works because `bot.get_user` fetches the user object from a cache which may have not been populated right when the bot starts.

However, `bot.fetch_user` fetches the User object from the discord servers, which is also why you need to use the `await` keyword.